# Cmake, how to get actual command string

Tags: cmake

I need to get an actual list of libraries that cmake command invokes.
A list may be:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework;/usr/lib/libmpi_cxx.dylib
```

and so on with eventual command containing for example

```
g++ ... /usr/lib/libmpi_cxx.dylib -framework Accelerate
```

How can I get the actual transformed library list?

Comment: Did you try `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)`?  Here's [the docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE) for it.

Comment: @Fraser i need to get the list programatically from inside cmake

Comment: Ah, right.  Gimme a minute.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the dependencies for a given target from the [LINK_LIBRARIES](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aLINK_LIBRARIES) property.  So, if your target is called `MyExe`, you can do:

```
get_target_property(Dependencies MyExe LINK_LIBRARIES)
```

Comment: hmm, comes out empty.  so is LINK_DEPENDS

Comment: OK - we're talking about dependencies added via `target_link_libraries` calls?  Works for me on Windows.

Comment: Sorry - I can't explain that, and I don't have access to an Apple just now.  If nobody else gets the answer, you could try posting a small example CMakeLists.txt which shows the issue just to make sure we're on the same page.

Comment: This is crazy... I tried to list dependencies for the same project, with the same CMake code on both Linux and Mac and it works flawlessly on Linux and gives "Dependencies-NOTFOUND" on Mac. Gonna try to do some more tests...

Comment: `LINK_LIBRARIES` has been added in CMake version 2.8.11. If you are using an earlier version, it will come out as empty.

Comment: @sakra Ah - right.  Yes I'm using 2.8.11.1 - I imagine that's the issue.  Thanks.